# Redisearch on Redis instead of Redis-Stack?

Tags: caching, redis, redisearch, redis-stack-server

I want to use Redisearch. But problem is there is no Redis-stack docker image in my Organization's private registry. There is Redis version 5 and 6 though.

Can I use Rediserach directly on Redis instead of Redis-stack or is there any other way to solve this problem.

I tried going through Redis and Redis-stack documentation. But There is nowhere mentioned if Redisearch will be compatible on Redis directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can compile your own RediSearch module and load it into a Redis server through the configuration file. See the repository on GitHub: https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/releases

Once you have built it, you'd amend your `redis.conf` to include something like this.  The user that `redis-server` runs as will need permission to see and execute this file:

```
loadmodule /full/path/to/redisearch.so
```

Note that if you also want to use the JSON document type with Search, you'll need the RedisJSON module: https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/releases